# Problem when inserting in a Sparse Matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, sparse-matrix

I have to implement the CSR matrix data structure in C++ using 3 dynamic arrays (indexing starts at 0) and I've got stuck. So I have to implement 2 functions:

1) `modify(int i, int j, TElem e)` - modifies the value of (i,j) to e or adds if (if it does not exist) or deletes it if e is null.

2) `element(int i, int j) const` - returns the value found on (i,j)

I wanted to test my code in the next way:

```
Matrix m(10, 10);
    for (int j = 0; j < m.nrColumns(); j++) {
        m.modify(4, j, 3);
    }                                                             
    for (int i = 0; i < m.nrLines(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m.nrColumns(); j++)
            if (i == 4)
                assert(m.element(i, j) == 3);
            else
                assert(m.element(i, j) == NULL_TELEM);
```

And I got a surprise to see that m.element(4,j) will be 0 for j in the range (0,8) and only 3 for j=9.

This is my implementation of element(int i, int j) :

```
    int currCol;
    for (int pos = this->lines[i]; pos < this->lines[i+1]; pos++) {
        currCol = this->columns[pos];
        if (currCol == j)
            return this->values[pos];
        else if (currCol > j)
            break;
    }
    return NULL_TELEM;
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int nrLines, int nrCols) {
    if (nrLines <= 0 || nrCols <= 0)
        throw exception();
    this->nr_lines = nrLines;
    this->nr_columns = nrCols;
    this->values = new TElem[1000];
    this->values_capacity = 1;
    this->values_size = 0; 
    this->lines = new int[nrLines + 1];
    this->columns = new TElem[1000];
    this->columns_capacity = 1;
    this->columns_size = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i <= nrLines; i++)
        this->lines[i] = NULL_TELEM;
}
```

This is the "modify" method:

```
TElem Matrix::modify(int i, int j, TElem e) {
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= this->nr_lines || j >= nr_columns)
        throw exception();
    int pos = this->lines[i];
    int currCol = 0;
    for (; pos < this->lines[i + 1]; i++) {
        currCol = this->columns[pos];
        if (currCol >= j)
            break;
    }
    if (currCol != j) {
        if (!(e == 0)) 
            add(pos, i, j, e);
    }
    else if (e == 0)
        remove(pos, i);
    else
        this->values[pos] = e;
    return NULL_TELEM;
}
```

And this is the inserting method:

```
void Matrix::add(int index, int line, int column, TElem value)
{
    this->columns_size++;
    this->values_size++;
    for (int i = this->columns_size; i >= index + 1; i--) {
        this->columns[i] = this->columns[i - 1];
        this->values[i] = this->values[i - 1];
    }
    this->columns[index] = column;
    this->values[index] = value;
    for (int i = line + 1; i <= this->nr_lines; i++)
        this->lines[i]++;
}
```

Can somebody help me, please? I can't figure out why this happens and I really need to finish this implementation these days. It's pretty weird that is sees those positions having the value 0.

So having the next test that starts in the next way, I get a memory acces violation:

```
Matrix m(200, 300);
    for (int i = m.nrLines() / 2; i < m.nrLines(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= m.nrColumns() / 2; j++)
        {
            int v1 = j;
            int v2 = m.nrColumns() - v1 - 1;
            if (i % 2 == 0 && v1 % 2 == 0)
                m.modify(i, v1, i * v1);
            else
                if (v1 % 3 == 0)
                    m.modify(i, v1, i + v1);
            if (i % 2 == 0 && v2 % 2 == 0)
                m.modify(i, v2, i * v2);
            else
                if (v2 % 3 == 0)
                    m.modify(i, v2, i + v2);
        }
```

The error is thrown in the method "modify" at currCol = this->column[pos];

And if I look into the debugger it looks like:i=168, lines[i]=-842150451, lines[i+1]=10180,pos=-842150451.

Does anybody have any ideas why it looks this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two small errors.

When you try to find the insertion position in `modify`, you loop over the non-empty elements in the row:

```
int currCol = 0;

for (; pos < this->lines[i + 1]; i++) {
    currCol = this->columns[pos];
    if (currCol >= j)
        break;
}
```

Here, you must update `pos++` in each iteration instead of `i++`.

The second error occurs when you insert an element into column 0. The `currCol` will be zero, but your condition for adding a new element is

```
if (currCol != j) {
    if (!(e == 0)) 
        add(pos, i, j, e);
}
```

But `j` is zero, too, so nothing will be inserted. You can fix this by starting with a non-existing column:

```
int currCol = -1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works perfectly on that test. Now I have another test and I get a memory acces violation error... I don't know why that happens. I'll edit the post right now and post it.

Comment: I'm glad it works now, but please don't edit the question after the fact. SO is supposed to be a repository of questions and answer, not a discussion. By editing the question my anser now refers to only a part of the question. I think you should open a new question if you face another problem.

Comment: On another note, you can also try to find out what's going on by printing the contents of your arrays after each step. The matrix is only 10x10 and you can see what's going on. (The weird indices look as if you had swapped in some gerbage from beyond the valid array limits.)

Comment: Well, reduce the test. It's quite likely that the same error will occur on a smaller matrix. Don't stick too close to the course script. You have to try out things!

Comment: It works perfectly on 20x30, but it should behave the same way on 200x300. There is no difference. And I get that memory acces violation. Also I've changed the size of vectors to [1000] but that isn't the problem.

Comment: I've added a new post for that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789166/c-memory-error-when-testing-a-bigger-matrix

Comment: "Also I've changed the size of vectors to [1000] but that isn't the problem. " -- Well, you are looping over half the rows and half the coluns nested, so you need at 150*100 slots for the elements. That's more than 1000. ´:)`

Comment: Oh :) I'll change to a dynamic array then, which rezizes when it need. Maybe it would work them

Comment: Yes, good idea. Given that you use C++, you can use `std::vector<TElem>` out of the box.

Comment: I know but the teachers don't let us use STLs now. They said that it's better to learn the arrays first, so you know what happens in the back at STLs.

Comment: Yep, thank you! Now this test passes, but I get an assertion fail on another test lol. it's a bigger test and it check m.element(i,j)==NULL_TELEMENT at some point.

Comment: Okay, next level. You can write a function that checks the sanity of your matrix: the row indices must be non-decreasing and be valid indices to columns and values. Call this function after each action. That will make your code slow, but that way you can see what exactly happens. For example, the bigger test might fail in `remove`, which you don't show. You can also run al lot of random tests on a small matrix with this sanity check to stress-test it.